# Closing Activity causes surface buffer errors with monogame

Tags: android, xamarin.android, monogame

I have a monogame game from which I'm launching an activity in order to login. The game runs fine. When I launch the activity it also runs fine and the gameloop appears to be blocked. The real problem comes when I Finish() the activity or perform OnBackPressed(). I get surface buffer errors, the screen goes black but the game loop resumes. If I try turning off Host GPU in the emulator, the app will instead crash when closing the activity.

```
When activity opens:
[EGL_emulation] tid 18496: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
[OpenGLRenderer] Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x81448da0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH


When back pressed in activity or calling Finish():
[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0xa4805a80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x82aff0b0)
[EGL_emulation] tid 18496: eglSurfaceAttrib(1210): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
[OpenGLRenderer] Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x81456b00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
[EGL_emulation] eglMakeCurrent: 0xa4805a80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x82aff0b0)
[Surface] getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x0
[EGL_emulation] tid 18458: swapBuffers(531): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
[IInputConnectionWrapper] finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
[EGL_emulation] egl_window_surface_t::swapBuffers called with NULL buffer
[EGL_emulation] tid 18458: swapBuffers(498): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
[EGL_emulation] egl_window_surface_t::swapBuffers called with NULL buffer
[EGL_emulation] tid 18458: swapBuffers(498): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
[EGL_emulation] egl_window_surface_t::swapBuffers called with NULL buffer
[EGL_emulation] tid 18458: swapBuffers(498): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
[EGL_emulation] egl_window_surface_t::swapBuffers called with NULL buffer
[EGL_emulation] tid 18458: swapBuffers(498): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
[EGL_emulation] egl_window_surface_t::swapBuffers called with NULL buffer
[EGL_emulation] tid 18458: swapBuffers(498): error 0x300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)

Without using host gpu it crashes with:
[Surface] getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7a697320
```

Comment: Before finishing activity, you should check that UI activities need to be suspended.Not turning off Host GPU directly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I ended up having to create my own soft keyboard in monogame and therefore no longer launch any android activities.